# Copy failed when building a docker image using Golang api

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a Docker Image using the official GO API, but I run into a problem on this line:

```
COPY packages /tmp/packages
```

of

```
"message":"COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder107969114/packages: no such file or directory"
```

Where packages is a folder in the directory where the docker file resides.

If I just build a docker image build to the path of the Dockerfile it builds as expected.

I tried adding a WORKDIR to the path where the Dockerfile is in the actual Dockerfile but it still seems like it can't find the folder.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: can you add your docker build command?

Comment: Important to point to the build context, and you can change it in the build command, `docker build -t my-image .` the dot points to where you're running the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else encounters into this problem, if you have any mounts for your host config like:

```
&container.HostConfig{
    Mounts:[]mount.Mount{
        {
            Source: .../somePath,
            Target: .../somePath,
        }
    }
}
```

That you built the image with the correct build context:

```
cli.ImageBuild(context.Background(), tarFile, types.ImageBuildOptions{})
```

That within the tarFile that you're passing, .../somePath exists.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled during one day to figure out how to build an image with the API, then I dived in the source code and found a neat solution which consist to used the tools provided by docker for the creation of archive, here is what I've found, it may help some people:

`import "github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive"
reader, err := archive.TarWithOptions("path/to/the/project/where/the/dockefile/reside", &archive.TarOptions{})`

Thus the TarWithOptions return what we need an Io.Reader to pass to the buildContext.
To go further and fit a special need, you can pass several argument as [TarOptions{}](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/pkg/archive/archive.go):

`TarOptions struct {
    IncludeFiles     []string
    ExcludePatterns  []string
    Compression      Compression
    NoLchown         bool
    UIDMaps          []idtools.IDMap
    GIDMaps          []idtools.IDMap
    ChownOpts        *idtools.Identity
    IncludeSourceDir bool
    // WhiteoutFormat is the expected on disk format for whiteout files.
    // This format will be converted to the standard format on pack
    // and from the standard format on unpack.
    WhiteoutFormat WhiteoutFormat
    // When unpacking, specifies whether overwriting a directory with a
    // non-directory is allowed and vice versa.
    NoOverwriteDirNonDir bool
    // For each include when creating an archive, the included name will be
    // replaced with the matching name from this map.
    RebaseNames map[string]string
    InUserNS    bool
}`